# Error putting superclass objects in lower bounded wildcard list

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I understand that using a lower bounded wildcard on a list as method parameter should let us put elements of that lower bound and its super types but consider following code:

```
public class WildcardError {
    void foo(List<? super Number> i) {
        i = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //compile error
        i.add(new Integer(2)); // no error
    }
}
```

Now here I understand why there is a compile error in the first statement of method foo as ArrayList of Integer is not a subtype of List of "? super Number" but then why are we allowed to put Integer in this list even though integer is not a supertype of Number? Also it is the other way around in following code:

```
public class WildcardError {
    void foo(List<? super Integer> i) {
        i = new ArrayList<Number>(); //no error
        Number k =20;
        i.add(k); // compile error
    }
}
```

Here I understand there should be no compile error in statement 2 since ArrayList of Number is a subtype of List of "? super Integer" but why is there a compile error on last statement?

Even though ? super Integer should accommodate super class Number.

I've tried to find the answer but can't search the exact scenario.

Answer (score 1):

On the first example, the lower bound `? super Number` means that the actual type parameter can be either `Number` or a supertype (e.g. `Object`).  Because Java's generics are invariant, a `List<? super Number>` can't match an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  Remember that the lower bound is a bound on the type parameter, not on the type of arguments that may be sent as an argument.  There is no error on the call to `add` because an `Integer` can be passed to the `add` method that may take a `Number` or a superclass.

On the second example, the lower bound `? super Integer` means that the actual type parameter can be either `Integer` or a supertype (e.g. `Number`, `Object`).  This matches `ArrayList<Number>`, so there is no error here.  However, the type of `i` is still `List<? super Integer>`, which is not guaranteed to be able to take a `Number` such as `k`.  It could at any time refer to a `List<Integer>` where a `Number` that could be a `Double` shouldn't be accepted.  This is why there is a compiler error here.